# Cómo agregar paginate() a esta consulta eloquent

Tags: laravel

Tengo esta consulta y requiero paginar los resultados:

```
public function index()
{
    $badges = Badge::all()->unique('code')->sortByDesc('id');
    return view('badges.index', compact('badges'));
}
```

Sí agrego `paginate()`

```
public function index()
{
    $badges = Badge::all()->unique('code')->sortByDesc('id')->paginate(25);
    return view('badges.index', compact('badges'));
}
```

Me muestra el siguiente error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.
```

Comment: De momento no necesito `where`, pero quizás si luego... Yo intenté quitando el `all()` antes y me dice lo siguiente: `BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Badge::unique() ` quizás el `where` lo soluciona, voy a agregarlo de una vez

Comment: No, debo guardar varios valores por transacción, y los guardo en una tabla pivote y los identifico con un mismo código (Cada registro) y con `unique()` hago que no se muestre repetido en el listado (Index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unique()` es un método que retorna una instancia de Collections, no de Query, por eso no puedes usar métodos Query posterior a `unique()`. Por otro lado, puedes usar **`distinct()`** que sí es un método Query.

```
$badges = Badge::distinct('code')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
```

Comment: Gracias, con la ayuda de ambos funciona!

Comment: Hola, disculpa, no funciona, pensé por un momento que sí.

Comment: Qué campos tiene tu tabla badge